# Insert a node at a specific position in a linked list using c

Tags: c

Can anyone tell me where I am doing wrong. I'm new to linked list data structures, here is my code:

Sample Input

```
3
16
13
7
1
2
```

Sample Output

```
16 13 1 7
```

Explanation

The initial linked list is `16 13 7`. We have to insert at the position which currently has in it. The updated linked list will be `16 13 1 7`

```
SinglyLinkedListNode *insertNodeAtPosition(SinglyLinkedListNode *head, int data, int position) {
    SinglyLinkedListNode *newNode = (SinglyLinkedListNode *)malloc(sizeof(SinglyLinkedListNode));
    newNode->data = data;

    if (head == NULL) {
        return newNode;
    }

    if (position == 0) {
        newNode->next = head;
        return newNode;
    }

    SinglyLinkedListNode *currentNode = head;

    while ((currentNode->next) != position) {
        currentNode = currentNode->next;
    }

    newNode->next = currentNode->next;
    currentNode->next = newNode;

    return head;
}
```

Wrong Answer

Your Output (stdout)
~ no response on stdout ~

Comment: I doubt this `(currentNode->next)!=position` comparison, doesn't compiler warn here ? `position` is an integer and `currentNode->next` is surely not an `int`.

Comment: @Achal yes compiler is warning here is there any way to avoid that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of comparing `(currentNode->next) != position`, which does not make sense as you are comparing a pointer to an integer, you should limit the number of nodes to skip and insert at this position. Be careful to stop before the end of the list to insert at the end in case `position` is too large.

```
SinglyLinkedListNode *insertNodeAtPosition(SinglyLinkedListNode *head, int data, int position) {

    SinglyLinkedListNode *newNode = (SinglyLinkedListNode *)malloc(sizeof(SinglyLinkedListNode));
    if (newNode == NULL) {
        printf("out of memory\n");
        return head;
    }

    newNode->data = data;

    if (head == NULL || position <= 0) {
        newNode->next = head;
        return newNode;
    }

    SinglyLinkedListNode *currentNode = head;

    while (currentNode->next != NULL && --position > 0) {
        currentNode = currentNode->next;
    }
    newNode->next = currentNode->next;
    currentNode->next = newNode;

    return head;
}
```

Comment: @SpandanKarmakar: thanks. There was also another bug in the posted code: `newNode->next` was not initialized to `NULL` if `head` was `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
while((currentNode->next)!=position) {}
```

*comparison is incorrect, you are comapring `int` type with `currentNode->next` which is not `int`*, compiler should have warned you if had compiled with proper flags like

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werroc test.c
```

Try this version

```
int itr = 0; 
while(currentNode != NULL && itr < position) { /* iterate till position & until currentNode not NULL. both condition must satisfy */
    currentNode=currentNode->next;
    itr++;
}
```

Comment: you shouldn't rely only on position in the loop as @chqrlie pointed. what if list is small & you are going on with doing `currentNode->next`, it may cause crash. Correct condition is `currentNode != NULL && itr < position`

Answer (score -2):

Do this-(This works on hackerrank)

```
 SinglyLinkedListNode* insertNodeAtPosition(SinglyLinkedListNode* head, int data, int position) {


SinglyLinkedListNode *newNode = (SinglyLinkedListNode*)malloc(sizeof(SinglyLinkedListNode));
newNode->data = data;

if (head == NULL) {
    return newNode;
}

if (position == 0) {
   newNode->next = head;
   return newNode;
}

   SinglyLinkedListNode* currentNode = head;

   int i=0;
    while((i!=position-1)
    {
        currentNode=currentNode->next;
        i++;
    }

newNode->next = currentNode->next;
currentNode->next = newNode;

return head;
 }
```